# .net smart card reader - GetDeviceSelector() - The member string SmartCardReader.GetDeviceSelector() is not implemented

Tags: c#, .net, smartcard

I'm making an app that should be able to read smard card from readers. I'm trying using SmartCardReader clas from Microsoft but I have some issue with following code:

```
internal class SmartCard
    {
        public async void Test()
        {
            string selector = SmartCardReader.GetDeviceSelector();
            DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();

            foreach (DeviceInformation device in devices)
            {
                SmartCardReader reader = await SmartCardReader.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I'm trying debug I get "The member string SmartCardReader.GetDeviceSelector() is not implemented".

I'm using Uno.UI in ver.4.8.15. Maybe something changed in the call method. Does anyone have any experience using this pack? Maybe there is some other way to handle Smart Card in .net?

Comment: First make sure the device is properly installed.  Try reading a file from the card read using File Explorer.  This will make sure the driver is installed properly.  Use Vendor drivers not generic Microsoft driver.   The card usually has two drivers.  One for the Reader and one for the Card.  The card and read has to be compatible since there are different versions of cards and readers.  Once you get the card installed it is locked with a key and you have to unlock.  Cards have different size addresses (8,16,32,64) and different data sizes (8,16,32,64) and unlocking has to work with sizes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I belive the problem starts much earlier. If it's even problem with device etc. I should rather get a exception that the device is missing, not that the method is missing.

Comment: If you do not have driver installed the device may not be recognized as a smart card.